# How to address someone with a split last name in an email?

Tags: united-states, email, name

How would I address someone with the name, Sasha de Lis, in an email?

- Affiliation: We've never met.
- Country: United States

Would I address the email as:

Dear Ms. de Lis?

Answer (score 5):

In general, this is culture dependent. *If* de Lis is of Dutch origin, then ["Ms. de Lis" is correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dutch_family_names), although you could even go so far as to maintain the Dutch title which I *think* is "Mevr." or "Mevrouw".

However... for just about every professional interaction I've ever had, "Dear Sasha" would be absolutely fine.

Comment: Yup, "Dear X" never fails when in doubt

Comment: There are situations in which people may not want to be addressed by their first name, so I would be properly addressed as Mr. Thornley rather than David.

Comment: Note that Sasha is a unisex name. A genderless address might be safer.

Answer (score 3):

I would open with **hi**  e.g. "**Hi Sasha**". I don't like seeing and using **dear**, because it's too familiar. I reserve **dear** for those I have a closer relationship with such as close friends and family.

Comment: That's a perfectly fine personal preference but it doesn't seem like the kind of thing I would _advise_ to other people. As far as I know, "dear" is not widely understood that way, and if someone else likes to use "dear" as a salutation, no need to talk them out of it IMO. (cf. https://www.askamanager.org/2015/10/is-it-rude-to-start-an-email-without-dear.html as a sample of someone else who thinks along similar lines)

Comment: @DavidZ I disagree. I worked in business development in an international company based in the US that interacts across multiple industries i.e. I interacted with a lot of different kinds of people through email. No one used "Dear" in emails directed to me nor did they do so in forwarded emails directed to my colleagues. I personally dislike seeing "dear" for the reasons stated above and it's possible that OP is interacting with someone like myself. Why not go with a less "risky" option?